# The value from script_field does not return native value

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to create a new field from existing fields, aka `request_uri`,

The original query returns,

```
{
   ...
      "hits" : [
         {
            "_type" : "xx",
            "_index" : "xx",
            "fields" : {
               "request_uri" : [
                  "/static/image/smiley/default/shocked.gif"
               ]
            },
            "_id" : "AUx5EnoynHZzwsDrHRRb",
            "_score" : 1
         }
      ],
      "total" : 2
   }
}
```

Now if I create a script_field base on the `request_uri` field,

```
{
  "script_fields": {
    "isAnImage": {
      "script": "doc['request_uri'].value"
    }
  }
}
```

The `isAnImage` returns `default`. Which means it's not the original value but an array of analyzed keywords

Which just contradicts the document ...

Am I wrong about something?

I need to get the original `request_uri` string and do something about it, but I couldn't retrieve the correct string.

[image]

Comment: Try using _source instead of doc. Inefficient, because it forces a load of the source, but it might do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

When you are hitting doc object , your requests are getting routed to the reverse reverse index or field data cache. Here you can only access the analyzed data as an array.

In case you need the ray data , you need to hit _source rather than doc.
This would be highly slow , but then you will get the right value.
Another option would be to maintain url as [not_analyzed](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/mapping-core-types.html) so that you the field data cache will have the entire information as a single token.
Here doc will give you the entire string and the same time your performance wont get affected.